# Mongoid Query Embedded Document Return Wrong Record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I have two models `Core::User` and `Core::UserMeta` :

```
class Core::User
   include Mongoid::Document

   embeds_many :core_user_meta, class_name: 'Core::UserMeta'
end
```

```
class Core::UserMeta
   include Mongoid::Document

   field :meta_key, type: String
   field :meta_value

   embedded_in :core_user, class_name: 'Core::User'
end
```

I'm using 2 criterias for the query `Core::UserMeta` on `Core::User` looks like :

```
Core::User.where('core_user_meta.meta_key': 'roles', 'core_user_meta.meta_value': 'member').first
```

I want to get a record has criterias `"roles"` in `meta_key` **and** `["member"]` in `meta_value` but the result always, looks like I'm using `or` clause instead of `and` clause

```
#<Core::User _id: BSON::ObjectId('5b961b07eea19009d397cfaf'), core_user_meta: [{"_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('5b961b07eea19009d397cfb0'), "meta_key"=>"nickname", "meta_value"=>"member"}, {"_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('5b961b07eea19009d397cfbb'), "meta_key"=>"roles", "meta_value"=>["subscriber"]}]>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query, as written, is:

> Give me a user which has a meta with meta_key of 'roles' and which has a meta with meta_value of 'member'.

This query is satisfied with a user object that has two metas, each of the metas satisfying one of the conditions.

To impose both conditions on the same meta, use $elemMatch:

```
Core::User.where('core_user_meta'=>{'$elemMatch'=>{'meta_key': 'roles', 'meta_value': 'member'}}).first
```